# Passbook Update Push not shown on Lockscreen

Tags: ios6, apple-push-notifications, passbook

I am playing with apples Passbook service. I have a really strange behaviour on all devices. If I send a push via APNS to the device to let them know that there is a update for a certain pass they do the update but they do not show any notification on the Lockscreen on the device.

Right now I am logging the whole communication between my PHP-Webservice and the APNS. I always answer with headre 200, and the requested answer. (1st Serials; 2nd Pass.pkpass)  and the device does the update as I can see in the passbook app but as I already said I do not get any Notification on the Lockscreen. The Device is set up correctly as described in this article: [a link](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5483)

and I do my APNS Request like this:

```
public function sendePushNotification($passTypeID, $debug = true)
{
// Zertifikat vorhanden ?
$certFullPath = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "api/cert/ck.pem";
if (file_exists($certFullPath))
{
  /**
   * Payload vorbereiten
   */
  $message = 'PASSDROP UPDATE'; 
  $body = array();
  $body['aps'] = array('alert' =>  $message);


  /**
   * Host bestimmen
   */
  $apnsHost = "gateway.push.apple.com";   // Development Umgbung

  /**
   * Stream erstellen
   */
  $ctx = stream_context_create();
  stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $certFullPath);
  $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':2195', $err, $errstr, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
  if (!$fp) 
  {
    echo "Fehler beim APNS: " . $err . " / ". $errstr. "\n";
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Payload versenden
   */
  $payload = json_encode($body);
  $msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $this->token)) . pack("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;      
}
else
{
  throw new Exception("Zertifikat-Bundle " . $certFullPath . " existiert nicht !!!");
}
}
```

As far as I know Apple does not read the payload when pushing a Pass in Passbook.

Does anybody have a hint for me what I can try next?
Do I need anything in the pass.json file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your devices are updating and receiving the new passes, but you are not seeing a notification then it is most likely that your pass.json doesn't contain a changeMessage key.

In order for a notification to display:

- a pass data value must have changed (field labels, colours and images do not trigger updates), and
- the changed field must include the changeMessage key, preferably with a %@ placeholder that will be replaced with the new field value.

For Passbook, the APNS push's only purpose is to notify the device that the web service has fresh content.  All notification activity is determined by the differences between the old and new pass.json files.

If your pass field is changing, and you have a changeMessage key set but you are not seeing a notification, then posting the relevant before and after sections of pass.json may help us identify what's wrong.

The json excerpts below will trigger the follwoing two notifications when the 'after' pass replaces the 'before' pass:

- Please proceed to gate 22
- Flight Status: Boarding

Before pass:

```
  "boardingPass": {
        "headerFields": [{
            "key": "h1",
            "value": "--",
            "label": "Gate",
            "changeMessage": "Please proceed to gate %@"
        }, {
            "key": "h2",
            "value": "On Time",
            "label": "Status",
            "changeMessage": "Flight status: %@"
        }],
           ...
```

After pass:

```
  "boardingPass": {
        "headerFields": [{
            "key": "h1",
            "value": "22",
            "label": "Gate",
            "changeMessage": "Please proceed to gate %@"
        }, {
            "key": "h2",
            "value": "Boarding",
            "label": "Status",
            "changeMessage": "Flight status: %@"
        }],
           ...
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the response. Can you go in detail with the changeMessageKey? I do not have any of these Values in my pass.json

Comment: I think this link would be very helpful for everybody, especially the change Key [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/PassKit_Bundle.pdf)

Comment: @soma-web - I've added an example to help.

Comment: I wanted to ask how will the pass.json look with changeMessage if the only thing I updated was the locations (latitude, longitude values). Should I just add changeMessage key in every location dictionary along with latitude and longitude key ? (I tried that and pass went invalid)

Comment: Very helpful, I don't know why they not mentioned this here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Creating.html

Comment: In this PHP code, There is no pass.json include. In my case, I just generated pkpass file into apple device directly. So where should I update pass.json file. Please help on this.

Comment: A .pkpass bundle contains a pass.json file.  I suggest to review the Apple documentation, since without a thorough understanding of the basics, you’ll struggle to get very far.

Comment: @PassKit In create Pass demo, I just generated .pkpass bundle in mobile device directly and did not store any where in server. Now In push notification code there is no way to update that mobile device's pass.json file. So I'm confused how to send update that file. Please give me a link of demo or Apple documentation. Please help me to understand this workflow.

Comment: You have to generate a new .pkpass bundle each time.  You also need to implement the Webservice API for the device to be able to request the updated bundle from your server.  https://developer.apple.com/wallet.

Comment: @PassKit Thanks for your prompt reply. Yes I can create Webservice API for device to request for updated pass bundle. But As per my understanding, first push notification service will call and it will send push notification to device and then that API will be called from the device. My issue is Push notification is not working for that updated pass. So device can't know that Pass has update and It will not call update pass API. There is no issue in my push notification code. Still That device is not receiving any notification for the pass.

Comment: Make sure you are connecting to APNS with the PassTypeId certificate, not a man APNS certificate.  Then hook your iPhone up to a Mac and check its logs as you send the push.  You need an iPhone and a Mac to test.  The iOS simulator doesn’t accept pushes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196967/discussion-between-dharmesh-goswami-and-passkit).

Comment: @PassKit I have iPhone and a Mac to Test. PHP code is showing successful message to connect APNS server. But after that I can't track what happened to that Push. Could you please help me that How can I check log into Mac by connection my app and iPhone? I have iPhone developer with me, so Please just give some more details to track that Push request.