# Apple wallet lock screen notification on pass update

Tags: ios, wallet

I have a problem with showing apple pass notification in lock screen. I have created the pass and I could update the fields from my pass server when there is an update but when the screen is locked I'm not able to show any lock screen notifications about the pass updates.

As per the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Creating.html) I think we can only show date or locations based notification in lock screen. Is there any other way I can show other notifications like "package is delayed for 2 hours" or something like that in lock screen on pass update?

Comment: I got the answer form here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209815/passbook-update-push-not-shown-on-lockscreen . Thanks!